# Are these equivalent: "sea sight" vs "sea view"

Tags: sentence-construction

Are these two sentences equivalent:

> I want a room with a sea **view**.
>
> I want a room with a sea **sight**.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you mean "sea" instead of "see".

No, they are not the same. The first sentence is not grammatical, but you can change it:

> I want a room with a sea view.

A better way to say the same thing might be:

> I would like a room with a view of the sea.

Your second example sentence is not grammatical.

Comment: tnx i edited the question..

Comment: believe it not I copied the first sentence from a book!

Comment: Why am I not surprised?

Comment: the book supposed to be grammatically correct! anyway.